# how to slowly show element in vanilla js? My main concern is to show this element slowly

Tags: javascript, show

```js
$(".warning").show("slow");
```

```css
body {
  background: #2d3339
}
.warning {
  border: 5px solid #e1dfbe;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
    display: none;
}
.warning span {
  color: #f4f3ce;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="warning">
    <span>Lorem ips</span>
  </p>
```

how to write $(".className").show("slow") in vanilla js? My main concern is to show this element slowly.

[like this in jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/qj3jf4aw/)

Comment: [This](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) might help

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want some kind of fade effect? You can try doing something with CSS transitions to change the opacity. Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kgb86ng/1/). You can make it slower/faster by changing the amount of time the transition takes.

HTML:

```
<p id="my-para">Hello, my name is John</p>
<button id="btn">Show Element</button>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .9s ease;
}
```

JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('my-para').classList.add('fade-in');
});
```